# No power in master bath

Tags: electrical, bathroom, circuit-breaker

The power in my master bath worked at 2pm when I left my house and was not working when I returned home.  This is the only room in the house that does not have any power.  Nothing on the breaker box has flipped.  To be safe I turned everything off and back on again.  Nothing is working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have any outlets in there that have a "test"/ "reset" button?  The outlet could even be in another room.

Comment: Are the lights and the receptacle in this bathroom on the same circuit? Are the lights working? Is the receptacle protected by a GFCI breaker or by  GFCI receptacle?

Answer (score 2):

Look around for a tripped GFCI - or just press the reset buttons on any GFCIs you can find.

Also, TRY turning the correct breaker (hopefully they are properly labelled, if not, correct that this week) off and then back on - sometimes they don't "look tripped" but they are. (or was that what you meant by "turning everything off and back on again" - not clear where you did that.) If it's a GFCI breaker, try the test/reset on it as well.

The GFCI may not be in the bathroom - people make odd choices when laying things out sometimes. It might be in another bathroom (since you can share a bathroom circuit) or some other room entirely.

Comment: I have taken several service calls to houses that the bathroom was connected through a GFCI in the garage. (This is not allowed by current NEC.)

Comment: Well, that would be a challenge to find...

Comment: Plain outlets fed from GFCIs elsewhere MUST have a "GFCI Protected" sticker or it's a codevio. (so that dumb home inspector to redflagged the bathroom outlet protected by a GFCI breaker was right after all).  You are allowed to make your own sticker.  So you might as well make one that says where the reset button is :)

Comment: ...and we all know that even if those stickers are put on, they are cheap crap and fall off.